# JavaScript Object Literal - Data Manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object literal with an array of objects(which are books) and methods I need to get "publisher" property with the most "books" and I am not sure how to do it.

This is what I've done so far:

```
const Library = {
  _books: [
    {
      title: 'World of Warcraft: Cycle of Hatred',
      author: 'Keith DeCandido',
      publisher: 'Pocket Star',
      year: 2006
    }
  ],
  // Add Books Method
  addBook: function(book) {
    return typeof book === 'object' ? this._books.push(book) : console.log(`Please enter a valid book.`);
  },
  // Publisher w/ Most Books
  manyBooks: function() {
    return this._books.reduce((books, book) => book.publisher)
  }
}

// Add Books to the Library
Library.addBook({
  title: 'The Witcher: The Last Wish',
  author: 'Andrzej Sapkowski',
  publisher: 'Ciela',
  year: 2016
});

Library.addBook({
  title: 'Fire and Blood',
  author: 'George Martin',
  publisher: 'Bard',
  year: 2019
});

Library.addBook({
  title: 'Song of Fire and Ice',
  author: 'George Martin',
  publisher: 'Bard',
  year: 2001
});

// Print results in the console
console.log(`Total Books in the Library:`, Library.getBooks());
console.log(`Publisher With Most Books:`,  Library.manyBooks());
```

Here's my entire code: https://repl.it/@natefr0st/Objects

Comment: please add the wanred result as well. what happens if all publisher has the same amount of books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group books by a publisher and then get the publisher with the max of books.

```
const groupBy = (items, key) => items.reduce(
  (result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[key]]: [
      ...(result[item[key]] || []),
      item,
    ],
  }), 
  {},
);
```

...

```
// Publisher w/ Most Books
manyBooks: function() {
    publishers = groupBy(this._books, "publisher")

    return Object.keys(publishers)
                 .reduce((a, b) => publishers[a] > publishers[b] ? a : b)
}
```

`groupBy` can be looks like that to return only count not list of books:

```
const groupBy = (items, key) => items.reduce(
  (result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[key]]: (result[item[key]] || 0) + 1,
  }), 
  {},
);
```

`manyBooks` function to get list of publishers with the max of books:

```
manyBooks: function() {
    publishers = groupBy(this._books, "publisher")
    maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(publishers))
    return Object.keys(publishers) 
                 .filter((val) => publishers[val] == maxCount);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by aggregating an object with books per publisher:

```
var publishers = this._books.reduce((publishers, book) => { 
   publishers[book.publisher] = (publishers[book.publisher]||0)+1;
   return publishers;
}, {});
```

You can then sort the keys of that object:

```
var publishersByBooks = Object.keys(publishers).sort((a,b) => publishers[a] == publishers[b] ? 0 : publishers[a] > publishers[b] ? -1 : 1);
```

With this, `publishersByBooks[0]` will be the publisher with the most books. It may or may not be that `publishersByBooks[1]` has equally many books. It is up to your implementation what you want to do with that. You can access `publishers[publishersByBooks[0]]` to get the number of books for that publisher.

Comment: When I try to console.log it ```console.log(`Publisher With Most Books:`,  Library.manyBooks());``` it returns  "Publisher With Most Books: undefined"

The method I used:

`manyBooks: function() {
    // return this._books.reduce((books, book) => book.publisher)
    this._books.reduce((publishers, book) => { 
      publishers[book.publisher] = (publishers[book.publisher] || 0) + 1;
      return publishers;
   }, {});
  }`

Comment: @KevinZino: Your commented-out line had a return statement, which is now missing. Right now, `manyBooks` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Library = {
  _books: [
    {
      title: 'World of Warcraft: Cycle of Hatred',
      author: 'Keith DeCandido',
      publisher: 'Pocket Star',
      year: 2006
    }
  ],
  // Add Books Method
  addBook: function(book) {
    return typeof book === 'object' ? this._books.push(book) : console.log(`Please enter a valid book.`);
  },
  // Publisher w/ Most Books
  manyBooks: function() {
    return this._books.reduce((books, book) => book.publisher)
  },
  
  getBooks(){
   listOfBooks= this._books.map(element => {
      return element
    });
    return listOfBooks
    
    },    
    manyBooks(){
   listOfBooks= this._books.map(element => {
      return element.publisher
    });
    return listOfBooks
    
    }
}

// Add Books to the Library
Library.addBook({
  title: 'The Witcher: The Last Wish',
  author: 'Andrzej Sapkowski',
  publisher: 'Ciela',
  year: 2016
});

Library.addBook({
  title: 'Fire and Blood',
  author: 'George Martin',
  publisher: 'Bard',
  year: 2019
});

Library.addBook({
  title: 'Song of Fire and Ice',
  author: 'George Martin',
  publisher: 'Bard',
  year: 2001
});

console.log(`Total Books in the Library:`, Library.getBooks());
console.log(`Publisher With Most Books:`,  Library.manyBooks());
```